# IIS7 Profiling

Tags: iis-7, profiling, administration

Is there a way to profile IIS7? (freeware?)

- Number of connections
- Bandwidth usage
- Errors (Event Viewer?)
  -...

thx, Lieven Cardoen

ps: Something similar to mssqlserver profiling

Comment: read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831704(v%3dws.11)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try out the [Administration Pack for IIS 7.0](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1682&g=6).  It has:

**Configuration Editor:**
The configuration editor module will help you manage your configuration files.  This tool is available for server administrators only.  It allows you to edit any section, attribute, element or collection in your configuration file.  In addition to editing these values you are also able to lock and unlock them.  The configuration editor also allows you to generate scripts based on the actions you take as well as search the file to see where values are being used.

**IIS Reports:**
The IIS Reports module enables you to view key statistics about your website.  You can also generate your own module reports to gather information relevant to you and your business.  Currently you can view the output of these reports as charts and/or tables.

**Database Manager:**
This module is no longer part of the Administration Pack and instead is offered as a separate download in the IIS Download Center.

**UI Extensions:**
UI Extension modules allow you to manage existing features through IIS Manager.

- The FastCGI module allows you to manage your FastCGI settings.
- The two ASP.NET modules allow you to manage your authorization and custom errors settings.
- Finally the HTTP Request Filtering allows you to setup rules for http request filtering.

Comment: Dont think Admin Pack is available anymore

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing quite like MSSQL's profiler, but a set of tools:

- Perfmon will show you the # of current connections per website. Perfmon.msc, web service, current connections, select website, click add.  Don't like the interactive nature of perfmon? No problem, use logman.exe, a nice CLI for perfmon.
- Bandwidth usage you can get from your log files if you enable bytes sent  & bytes received in your iis log files.   This is also available via performance counters - web service, bytes sent/received/sec.  I think the two complement each other fairly well.
- IIS7 has a new feature called Failed Request Tracing.  You can tell it to log on all 500's,or any .aspx page that takes 15 seconds to run, or based on event severity. It saves all of this information in an XML file for you under \inetpub so it's easily parseable, and also gives you a nice XSLT to view it in your browser and drill down if you like.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis7/

Comment: This is a better answer. At least it mentions perfmon.